# Does the Ripple protocol allow listing an account's (address's) past transactions? If yes, is there a web site for this?

Tags: ripple, bitcoin-core-accounts

There are many well known sites that show balance and past transactions for a *Bitcoin* address, eg. blockchain.info, blockr.io etc. Does something like this exist for Ripple? Is this even possible with the Ripple protocol?

I know about http://rippledb.com/, but this doesn't seem to list this, just ledgers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Ripple protocol does allow you to list all past transactions performed. The most typical way would be to use the [**`account_tx`**](https://ripple.com/build/websocket-tool/#account_tx) command. You can "page through" the data, retrieving a particular number of transactions per command, until you get to the first transaction.

I am not aware of a website where you can trace through an account's transaction history using GUI-style navigation, although the [Ripple Charts Account Explorer](http://www.ripplecharts.com/#/graph) will show you an account's transaction stream.